# Flask JSON request is None

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working on my first Flask app (version 0.10.1), and also my first Python (version 3.5) app. One of its pieces needs to work like this:

1. Submit a form
2. Run a Celery task (which makes some third-party API calls)
3. When the Celery task's API calls complete, send a JSON post to another URL in the app
4. Get that JSON data and update a database record with it

Here's the relevant part of the Celery task:

```
if not response['errors']: # response comes from the Salesforce API call
    # do something to notify that the task was finished successfully
    message = {'flask_id' : flask_id, 'sf_id' : response['id']}
    message = json.dumps(message)
    print('call endpoint now and update it')
    res = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/transaction_result/', json=message)
```

And here's the endpoint it calls:

```
@app.route('/transaction_result/', methods=['POST'])
def transaction_result():
    result = jsonify(request.get_json(force=True))
    print(result.flask_id)
    return result.flask_id
```

So far I'm just trying to get the data and print the ID, and I'll worry about the database after that.

The error I get though is this: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: None: Max retries exceeded with url: /transaction_result/ (Caused by None)`

My reading indicates that my data might not be coming over as JSON, hence the Force=True on the result, but even this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried doing the same request in CocoaRestClient, with a Content-Type header of application/json, and I get the same result.

Because both of these attempts break, I can't tell if my issue is in the request or in the attempt to parse the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `request.get_json(force=True)` returns an object (or None if `silent=True`). `jsonify` converts objects to JSON strings. You're trying to access *str_val*.flask_id. It's impossible. However, even after removing redundant `jsonify` call, you'll have to change `result.flask_id` to `result['flask_id']`.

So, eventually the code should look like this:

```
@app.route('/transaction_result/', methods=['POST'])
def transaction_result():
    result = request.get_json()
    return result['flask_id']
```

And you are absolutely right when you're using REST client to test the route. It crucially simplifies testing process by reducing involved parts. One well-known problem during sending requests from a flask app to the same app is running this app under development server with only one thread. In such case a request will always be blocked by an internal request because the current thread is serving the outermost request and cannot handle the internal one. However, since you are sending a request from the Celery task, it's not likely your scenario.

**UPD:** Finally, the last one reason was an IP address `0.0.0.0`. Changing it to the real one solved the problem.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm not sure if I had tried this before, but I still get the `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: None: Max retries exceeded with url: /transaction_result/ (Caused by None) ` error, even though the Celery task is able to print the JSON correctly.

Comment: @JonathanStegall, try to change IP address from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 or your real address (if any). And what is the result of using a REST client?

Comment: It seems to finally have worked once I tried a test Heroku URL. Maybe I have an issue with my local version, as it didn't work with localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Would you want to put that as an answer so I can accept?